# How can I set the homepage of my website as "/"?

Tags: html, url

I want to ask if this is possible to set my homepage as the slash icon without showing name of the file.

---

Files are on the localhost and,for example I want it to be

> localhost/

instead of

> localhost/file.html

Comment: Rename `file.html` to `index.html`.

Comment: …or configure your web server to treat `file.html` as the default file…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either achieve this by naming your starting page file "index.html" that way you could access the homepage just with "localhost/"

If you want another name for your Index-File you could also write the following code in your .htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
```